# Django on IronPython

Tags: python, django, ironpython

I am interested in getting an install of Django running on IronPython, has anyone had any success getting this running with some level of success?

If so can you please tell of your experiences, performance, suggest some tips, resources and gotchas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Besides the Jeff Hardy blog post on [Django + IronPython](http://jdhardy.blogspot.com/2008/12/django-ironpython.html) mentioned by Tony Meyer, it might be useful to also read Jeff's two other posts in the same series on his struggles with IronPython, easy_install and zlib. The first is [Solving the zlib problem](http://jdhardy.blogspot.com/2008/12/solving-zlib-problem-ironpythonzlib.html) which discusses the absence of zlib for IronPython; hence, no easyinstall. Jeff reimplemented zlib based on ComponentAce's zlib.net. And finally, in [easy_install on IronPython, Part Deux](http://jdhardy.blogspot.com/2008/12/easyinstall-on-ironpython-part-deux.html) Jeff discusses some final tweaks that are needed before easy_install can be used with IronPython.

Comment: While I haven't tried it myself, the latest IronPython release (Dec 2014) includes `ensurepip`, so `pip` should be guaranteed to both be installed and work properly.

Answer (score 8):

[Here's a database provider that runs on .NET & that works with Django](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinoviehland/archive/2008/03/17/ironpython-ms-sql-and-pep-249.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This was [demoed](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/03/django-and-ironpython) at last year's PyCon (the [details](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinoviehland/archive/2008/03/17/ironpython-ms-sql-and-pep-249.aspx) are also available).  More recently, [Jeff Hardy has blogged about this](http://jdhardy.blogspot.com/2008/12/django-ironpython.html), including suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Django is yet working on IronPython, but I'm not saying it cannot be done.

[Django-ironpython](http://bitbucket.org/jdhardy/django-ironpython/overview) project is a work currently underway to run Django on IronPython. The project has reported [65.7% test pass rate](http://twitter.com/#!/djangoipy) with sqlite on 2nd of May 2010.