# Is there a Django or Rails for the .Net Platform?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, django

Now before I dive too far into this this question, I am aware of nDjango and MonoRail; however, those project seem to be lacking.

What I'm wondering is if there is a solution out in the .Net world that has the following features out of a single box like Rails has in Ruby or Django has for Python.  I know tools that do pieces but am curious if there's 1 unified solution out there.

- Database Versioning/Migrations
- ORM or similar code gen
- MVC-based
- Pre-generated administrative screens
- View generation
- Theming / styling
- (I'm sure I'm forgetting another cornerstone feature)

There's lots of options that cover one or more of these aspects but is there something in .Net that covers all of them?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, Django doesn't really do migrations out of the box, you have to use South (http://south.aeracode.org/) or other similar projects.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - This is true; however, it is something that Rails provides which is why I placed it up there.  There's always tools that can fill in the gaps like you pointed out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not yet found a solution as you have described, but as you know there are bits and pieces that could be used together to provide a stack that is close:

- Database Versioning/Migrations - [DotNetMigrations](http://www.codeplex.com/dotnetmigrations)
- ORM or similar code gen - [Nhibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html), [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- MVC-based - native to [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)
- Pre-generated administrative screens - [PLINQO](http://plinqo.com/)
- view generation - available in Entity Framework or [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) templates, PLINQO
- Theming / styling - native to ASP.NET

This would provide a stack that is .NET and not another ecosystem sitting on top of a .NET substrate.

Answer (score 2):

[You can actually run Rails under the .NET DLR](http://www.iunknown.com/2008/05/ironruby-and-rails.html). This allows you to not only access the feature set Rails provides, but also everything else which is available in the .NET ecosystem.

I haven't found a one click installer which gives me everything on your list, but, as you say, I have found excellent solutions for each point on your list which integrate well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not sure how close this gets you, but [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) seems to be trying to cover a lot of this ground in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [django for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425990/django-on-ironpython), the name is django!
In the web there is a lot of post about [django running with ironpython](http://www.google.com/search?&q=django+ironpython) (a implementation of python for the "virtual machine" of C#, CLR, i think)

Answer (score 0):

there is also [ndjango](http://ndjango.org) - the django templating language written in f# for .net. you can use it with [bistro](http://bistroframework.org) or asp.net mvc (or whatever else that you plug it into)